# Need comment about java pushbackInpuStream code translated to C#

Tags: c#, java, inputstream

This is the original java code it includes the **PushbackInputStream** class

```
public String readLine(InputStream in) throws IOException
{
    char buf[] = new char[128];
    int offset = 0;
    int ch;

    for (;;)
    {
        ch = in.read();
        if (ch == -1 || ch == '\n')
        {
            break;
        }
        else if (ch == '\r')
        {
       int tmpch = in.read();
         if (tmpch != '\n')
         {
              if (! (in instanceof PushbackInputStream))PushbackInputStream))
              {
                in = new PushbackInputStream(in);
              }
                 ((PushbackInputStream) in).unread(tmpch);
          }
          break;
            }
        else
        {
        if (offset == buf.length)
        {
           char tmpbuf[] = buf;
           buf = new char[tmpbuf.length * 2];
           System.arraycopy(tmpbuf, 0, buf, 0, offset);
        }
          buf[offset++] = (char) ch;
        }
   }
     return String.copyValueOf(buf, 0, offset);
}
```

Here is what i converted to C# , I implemented the **PushbackInputstream** with the **peek** method of the **StreamReader** class, however there is a keyword that i could not decipher like instanceof. Does the keyword "instanceof" matter in this situation?

```
    public String readLine(NetworkStream nsStream)
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(nsStream))
        {
            char[] buffer = new char[128];
            int offset = 0;
            int ch;

            for (; ; )
            {
                ch = reader.Read();
                if (ch == -1 || ch == '\n')
                {
                    break;
                }
                else if (ch == '\r')
                {

                    if ((reader.Peek()) == '\n')
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        reader.Read();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (offset == buffer.Length)
                    {
                        char[] tempBuffer = buffer;
                        buffer = new char[tempBuffer.Length * 2];
                        Array.Copy(tempBuffer, 0, buffer, 0, offset);
                    }
                    buffer[offset++] = (char)ch;
                }

            }
            return new string(buffer);
        }
    }
```

Any comment would be appreciated!

Comment: Ditch that Java stuff and its oldschool newline detection. What you need is a [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx) and its `ReadLine` method.

Comment: I can't get your meaning, the readline method returns data as string and i want a char!

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the network stream in a `StreamReader` and use its [`Peek()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.peek.aspx) method:

```
using(StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(someNetworkStream))
{
     int nextChar = streamReader.Peek();
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example? What do you mean wrappling network stream in streamReader? Thanx